# Interact with API to get user info after authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, hyperledger, github-api, hyperledger-composer, gitlab-api

I authenticated the REST server and got a token in the cookies. This token allowed access to the REST server, but I want to interact with the authentication service.

Github responses with that message

```
 {
      "message": "Bad credentials",
      "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
 }
```

Gitlab returns only

```
401 (Unauthorized)
```

I'm using token returned from cookies as HTTP header

```
Authorization: `token`
Authorization: bearer `token`
Authorization: token `token`
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is, but the authorization header for GItLab, unlike GitHub, should be `PRIVATE-TOKEN: exampleToken`, not `Authorization:`

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you posted some code that made it clearer what you're trying to do and where you might have gone wrong

Comment: someone else reported similar issues with Github auth here -> https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1067#issuecomment-199876644 (with possible resolutions added from there onwards)